# How to backup a postgres database using java

Tags: java, postgresql

this is the code I am using to back up my database using pg_dump 9.3 in java.
The problem I have is that always the result file is empty, and the exit code is 1, any ideas?

```
public static void backupDb() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p;
    ProcessBuilder pb;
    rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\pg_dumpall.exe",
            "--host", "localhost",
            "--port", "5432",
            "--username", "postgres",
            "--no-password",
            "--format", "custom",
            "--blobs",
            "--verbose", "--file", "D:\\service_station_backup.backup", "service_station");
    p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println(p.exitValue());
}
```

Comment: but why are you using java here?

Comment: Does the process / app have write access to the file location @Abdelwahhab ? Eg what is the user id of the process and does the user id have access to the output file?

Comment: @pnorton yes, the process can access the output file, the file is correctly created, but not content is dumped into it. i think the problem is with postgres server password.

Comment: Hi @no_pain_no_gain what does the postgresql log say  (show log_destination ;  log_destination 
-----------------
 stderr
(1 row)
 so for me its syslogs )? (journalctl |grep [Pp]ostgres |more ) You might need to turn up the logging. Could you show the contents of pg_hba.conf I might be able to help REF http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `psql`, the "long options" need an equal sign: `=`. So it needs to be e.g. `--host=localhost`. For that you need to pass those arguments as a single String argument to ProcessBuilder:

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\pg_dumpall.exe",
        "--host=localhost",
        "--port=5432",
        "--username=postgres",
        "--no-password",
        "--format=custom",
        "--blobs",
        "--verbose", "--file=D:\\service_station_backup.backup", "service_station");
```

You should also capture the error output of the ProcessBuilder using `ProcessBuilder.getErrorStream()` to see any error message from `psql`. You probably want to capture the regular output as well (using `getInputStream()`)

---

**Edit**

The error message you get:

> fe_sendauth: no password supplied

means you have to provide a password.

You can do that by passing a [connection URL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-connect.html#AEN39257) to pg_dump.

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\pg_dumpall.exe",
        "--dbname=postgres://postgres:password@localhost/postgres",
        "--format=custom",
        "--blobs",
        "--verbose", "--file=D:\\service_station_backup.backup", "service_station");
```

Comment: hi, thanks for following,i tried what you advised but still get the same result, and the same  message from the process ErrorStream : " fe_sendauth: no password supplied".

Comment: Then you need to provide a password. Either by setting the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable, by configuring it in `pgpass.conf` or by providing a connection URL. See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-connect.html#AEN39257

Answer (score 10):

thanks everyone for help, finally could find the perfect code.

```
public static void exportDb2() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p;
    ProcessBuilder pb;
    rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\pg_dump.exe",
            "--host", "localhost",
            "--port", "5432",
            "--username", "postgres",
            "--no-password",
            "--format", "custom",
            "--blobs",
            "--verbose", "--file", "D:\\service_station_backup.backup", "service_station");
    try {
        final Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
        env.put("PGPASSWORD", "admin");
        p = pb.start();
        final BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        String line = r.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.err.println(line);
            line = r.readLine();
        }
        r.close();
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println(p.exitValue());

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```